# alert dialog written in non activity class not showing alert dialog when dismissed from calling activity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I crate a class called "Dailog" for building alert dialog which has its own dismiss() method to dismiss the dialog. and then use it's Object in many screens where I need to show alert dialog.

In my calling Activity class I create instance of Dailog class, and then call up method which does some network operation(which is not async task) and then when network task is finished I dismis the dialog object. I need wait on the same screen untill networks operation finishes but with dialog showing something is happening.

While debugging I do see that that dialog object is not null. No exception throughout this execution but alert dialog never shows up

```
public class Dialog  {

    private AlertDialog dialog  ;
    private AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    public Dialog(Activity activity , String Message , String titleMsg) {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setMessage(Message);
        builder.setTitle(titleMsg);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.logoxl);
        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
 public void dismiss(){
        this.dialog.dismiss();
    }

}


// my activity method(openMenu) on button click where I am calling this 

public void OpenMenu(View view){
 Dialog progress = new Dialog(this , "We are fetching today's menu...Please Wait" , "Biji's Kitchen");
        try {
            Data fetcheddata = new Data(this);           
            fetcheddata.getMenu();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
 progress.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Data.getMenu()` is network operation and should be executed in the separate thread. `Dialog.dismiss()`, on the other hand, is UI operation and should be executed in main thread.

So, in `Data` thread you should wait for network request completion and then post message to UI thread to dismiss the dialog **after** that.

P.S. To be more clear: your current implementation **does** show dialog - and immediately dismisses it as `show` and `dismiss` are called one after another in UI thread but data is still loading in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting this Line. I hope it should work.

```
//progress.dismiss();
```

Comment: yes, it does shows up if I comment progress.dismiss but then the dialog appears in the screen after the network operation finishes not as soon as i click on button which calls up openMenu()